# SQL select rows where at least one value is something per id

Tags: mysql

I've looked at other answers to these questions and haven't seen one that fits exactly what I want.

So I have a table with ids and states and multiple records per id with different state values. How would I return a table only with the records where at least one record for an id is some value? so for example, if I have

```
 id|state
  1|CA
  1|ZZ
  1|ZZ
  2|NY
  2|CA
  3|NY
  4|IL
  4|ZZ
```

and I would like the ones where they had a record of being in NY

```
 id|state
  2|NY
  2|CA
  3|NY
```

Comment: `select * from TABLE_NAME where state = 'NY';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE state = 'NY');
```

Comment: Why would you do that instead of `WHERE state = 'NY'`?

Comment: @ragerory Check the desired output.

Comment: @BigRabbit Y not? Otherwise how will you get `2|CA`

Comment: @BigRabbit yes there is, he wants ALL records associated with an ID that has a NY record.

Comment: Yep noticed that what he required for output.

Comment: @Beginner touche mofo, touche!